# With IN Clause when Passing Collection as Parameter In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-variable

Query Gives O/p as

ItemSizeNM

(colName)

'U','V','X','Y'

But when I used this as input to IN Query in the Code Which I did.
It Doesn't Gives same resultset. Why This Happens...?
Table MstItemSize Has Proper Data.

> ```
>  declare @tblRingSize table ( ringSize varchar(100))        
>      declare  @ringSize varchar(100)         
>      select   @ringSize= cast((otherringSize) as varchar) 
>      from ##tempBand  where styleNo='BD00002';
> ```
>
> 1. INSERT INTO @tblRingSize SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitStrings_CTE (@ringSize, ',');
> 2. select ItemSizeNm from MstItemSize where SizeTypeNm ='Ring' and
>         ItemSizeNm
>         in --('U','V','X','Y')
>
>    ( select Replace  (
>        (select STUFF( (select ''',''' + ringSize from @tblRingSize For XML PATH('')),1,2,'')  +'''' ) 
>       ,' ',''))
> 3. select Replace  (
>        (select STUFF( (select ''',''' + ringSize from @tblRingSize For XML PATH('')),1,2,'')  +'''' ) 
>       ,' ','')

Comment: Try not using `varchar` but rather `varchar(100)`. Also why are you using a global ##temp table? What is the definition of SplitStrings_CTE? What is the data type of otherringSize in ##tempBand?

Comment: I Used Global temp because i Want to Use that table in other queries too.SplitStrings_CTE Function spilts comma separates charaters,
and datatype of  otherringSize is varchar(100)

Comment: Other queries *where*? Also I know what the split function does, but maybe it doesn't do it right (e.g. a varchar declaration could silently truncate your string). Where did you get the function?

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
from Here I got That Function SplitStrings_CTE

Comment: It is really tough to follow what you are doing or what output you expect. What is the *value* of `@ringSize`? Does it contain those string delimiters, so it is `@ringSize = '''U'',''V'',...';` What output do you expect?

Comment: Please add clarification information to the question, impossible to read in a comment.

Comment: 3rd Query Gives Me O/P as ` 'U','V','X','Y' `.
When I Copied this O/P and paste It in IN Clause as I Did in 2nd Query. It Gives Me a Results Which I want. 
But When I Passed 3rd Query to IN Clause in 2nd Query.I doesn't Give Proper Result. Which It should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `STUFF`, `FOR XML`, or `REPLACE` for the subquery:

```
select 
    ItemSizeNm 
from 
    MstItemSize 
where SizeTypeNm ='Ring' 
and ItemSizeNm  in (select ringSize from @tblRingSize)
```

Comment: It Give only First value. i.e U
I Want It as 

U

V

X

Y

Comment: Second Replace Gives me a proper Result as 'U','V','X','Y'

When I copied It and Pass It in IN Clause Which Commented It Works
Fine.
But When use that REPLACE statement It DOESN'T Work

Comment: It doesn't need to be formatted the same.  In fact it shouldn't be formatted at all -- the subquery should return a recordset, not a string that you build manually.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d89a9/4 Please See this Example. You Will Come to Know...Thrid query is not showing output...why..?

Comment: Because in your scenario, you are selecting that whole string into a recordset, and it is trying to match the whole string that you built to any one of the characters.  In order to do what you're trying to do (which again, is completely unnecessary), you'd have to build your whole SQL statement dynamically, like this:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d89a9/86